# How to make a bot that's events only take place in a certain server in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Say I wanted to have my bot send a certain message whenever something is sent in a server for example:

```
something = ["test, something"]

@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author == client.user: return
    channel = message.channel
    if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in something):
        await channel.send("yikers")
    else:
        return
```

How would I make this occur in only a specified channel, in a specified server?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just check `channel.id` to see if the message is in the correct channel:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author == client.user: return
    channel = message.channel
    if channel.id == 123:
        if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in something):
            await channel.send("yikers")
        else:
            return
```

You can get the id either by putting your desktop discord client in developer mode, or by adding a line like

```
print(f"{channel.name} {channel.id}")
```